# Which header defines malloc() on which platform?

Tags: c, malloc, header-files, multiplatform

I want to use `malloc()` in a C program which has to be cross-platform. But - where is it? I know that the C89 and C99 language standards require it to be available via `<stdlib.h>`, and yet - some platforms don't have it in there. I've noticed that in some cases it might be in `<malloc.h>`, and read that it could possibly be at `<malloc/malloc.h>`.

My question: Which platforms have `malloc()` in which locations? Specifically the three locations I mentioned?

Note: Please don't suggest I use a cross-platform development framework, that is not relevant in my case.

Comment: Check with the library docs in your platform.

Comment: According to standard, it is supposed to be in `stdlib.h`.

Comment: @SouravGhosh: I'm fine on _my_ platform, the point is I want the code to works on platforms other than mine... and I did say that the standard requires it to be in `<stdlib.h>`.

Comment: Could you provide an example of a platform that doesn't have `malloc` declared in `stdlib.h`?

Comment: Once again, there is nothing universal. You have to consult the docs for the target platform.

Comment: @einpoklum, in that case you definately have a non-conforming C compiler. Run fast, run far...

Comment: @GuntherSchulz: [TravisCI's xcode](https://github.com/eyalroz/ssb-dbgen/issues/53)...?

Comment: @SouravGhosh: I was hoping people here have a rule-of-thumb or list in mind.

Comment: Unless you are planning to tune the behaviour of `malloc()` or have to deal with some very improbable platforms, the answer is `<stdlib.h>`.  And I’m sorry to say that I regard Sourav’s cavilling as unwarranted.  This assumes you’re using a hosted implementation of C.  If you’re working with a freestanding implementation, you have to study the o/s facilities. There’s still a good chance the answer would be the same.

Comment: @einpoklum, the link you provided simply shows you build log, which explicitly states <malloc.h> not found. Again, try using <stdlib.h>, or alternatively updare your search paths in your project

Comment: @einpoklum That's a compiler complaining that `<malloc.h>` can't be found. It's not an example of `malloc()` not being declared by `<stdlib.h>`,

Comment: I think the proper way to deal with such nonconformat platforms is to detect this type of stuff in your build system's configure script (or the equivalent thereof).

Answer (score 5):

All conforming ***hosted*** C implementations have `malloc` in `<stdlib.h>`
Freestanding implementations are ***not required*** to provide `<stdlib.h>`

Some useful direct links to free PDF files of the C89/C90, C99 and C11 standards are listed below:

C89/C90 (ISO/IEC 9899:1990): https://www.pdf-archive.com/2014/10/02/ansi-iso-9899-1990-1/ansi-iso-9899-1990-1.pdf

C99 (ISO/IEC 9899:1999): http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf

C11 (ISO/IEC 9899:2011): http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf

C17/18 (ISO/IEC 9899:2018) https://web.archive.org/web/20181230041359if_/http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/abq/c17_updated_proposed_fdis.pdf

Comment: @EricPostpischil right you are, sir. Edited accoringly. However, OP gave link to build output in comments, which is clearly a hosted implemenation.

Answer (score 2):

As the question states the standard requires it to be declared in `<stdlib.h>`.
I do recommend checking your documentation. The standard is that it **must** be declared in that header but *may* be declared in other headers (directly or indirectly).

If you're targeting some non-conformant platform where it's not declared in `<stdlib.h>` the obvious answer is to `#include` that and `<stdlib.h>`. That way you're good on compliant platforms and the odd-ball you're aware of.

You could go so far as to have yet-another-header. Suppose it's only declared in  `<string.h>` then you could define a header in your project `"stdlibfix.h"` :

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
```

**NB:** Header guards omitted and in fact not required here.

If it exists in some non-standard header such as `<memory.h>` use conditional compilation. Most compilers define some macro identifying themselves such as SMITH_COMPILER then you'd need

```
#ifdef SMITH_COMPILER
#include <memory.h>
#endif
```

You may even encounter a platform that doesn't permit dynamic memory allocation such as a small embedded platform. How you deal with that is beyond the scope here except it's usually better to avoid it rather than implement it. In such applications you can and should calculate your maximum storage requirements and implement them as variables and fixed-size arrays.

Avoid just declaring its prototype:

```
void *malloc(size_t sz);
```

On some platforms `malloc()` may be declared differently (e.g. a different calling convention).

Given we're already talking about a non-compliant platform that doesn't declare it in `<stdlib.h>` extreme caution is surely order of the day.

**Footnote:** The real answer if `malloc()` isn't in `<stdlib.h>` is check the documentation, check your code for some silly error (e.g. appears to include `<stdlib.h>` but doesn't due to error in conditional compilation logic) then raise a ticket. 10 to 1 you've got some hobbyist compiler and maybe you should just fix `<stdlib.h>` as a favour to the project.